# How to define a property instead of public variable in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public static string SEARCH_STRING = "searchkey";
string key=Request.QueryString.Get(SEARCH_STRING);
```

How to change the above code to make SEARCH_STRING be accessed using a Property(get; set;) instead of a public variable

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? How is SEARCH_STRING being used? you see 7 answers below, all are correct, but none of them would be useful to you if your problem is something else. Describe your problem in detail.

Comment: all are correct only..but,here "SEAR" is used to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this variable will not be changed, it is better to use constant

```
public const string SEARCH_STRING = "searchkey";
```

and here is how you can make it property

```
private static string _searchString = "searchkey";
public static string SEARCH_STRING { 
  get { return _searchString; }
  private set { _searchString = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static string _searchString = "searchkey";
public static string SearchString { 
  get { return _searchString; }
  set { _searchString = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string SEARCH_STRING { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
class Foo {
static string m_searchString="searchKey";
public static string SEARCH_STRING
{
   get {return m_searchString;}
   set {m_searchString=value;}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're meaning? can probably set it to be readonly also if you're going to load its value at runtime...

```
public static string SEARCH_STRING 
{ 
    get
    {
        return "searchkey";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string SEARCH_STRING
    {
        get { return search_string; }
        set { search_string = value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string SEARCH_STRING
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For more encapsulation, use properties like this:

```
public string Name
{
    get;
    private set;
}
```

so the object of that class only can set it, other objects can read it only.